# How to get the value of a key from json in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my API I need to get the value from the "value" key of the readm pair.

```
"extra_info": [
                    {
                        "name": "readme",
                        "value": "**In this session, we will work on different activities using Toggle Board:**\nIdentify animals using characteristics\nRecognize the animals by listening to a song"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "skill",
                        "value": "Play school"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "sub_skill",
                        "value": "Toggle board"
                    }
                ],
```

I tried using like this but some case the index number will change.

```
hotsLevelController.other_list[0].extraInfo[0].value;
```

Comment: Have you thought about converting the JSON you have to actual data objects? That way you can iterate through the array and find the item you actually need. You can read more about serializing and deserializing JSON in Flutter [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47).

Comment: json in flutter is nothing but a Map data structure which can be represented as Map<String,dynamic> map. Use map["key_name"] to get the value and type cast the value from dynamic to your required data type for eg. to int, String, List etc

Answer (score 1):

Basic JSON serialization in Flutter is very simple. Flutter has a built-in dart:convert library that includes a straightforward JSON encoder and decoder.
You can learn from here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

or you can use this function:

```
// findKey will me 'readme' in your case
// pass the json data iin json
findValue(dynamic json, String findKey) {
  final data = json.decode(json) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  List<Map<String, String>> items = data['extra_info'] as List<Map<String, String>>;

  for (var item in items) {
    if (item['name'] == findKey) {
      return item['value'];
    }
  }
  return null; //not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a json response which is come from HTTP request.
so this can help you:

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  List<dynamic> itemsList = jsonResponse['extra_info'] as List<dynamic>;
  // print values
  for (var item in itemsList) {
    print((item as Map<String, String>)['value']);
  }
}
```